# No Link to OG Group Home in Group Details Block

Tags: organic-groups

Hello this is a problem thats always perplexed me. I once got around it by using Custom Breadcrumbs and having a link to the group home page there but since then ive had to remove custom breadcrumbs module and i think i would prefer another way of doing things.

Here's a post for example-
http://onlinebanter.com/diary/komps-daily-drivel/vietnam-saigon

As you can see there is no way to navigate back to the group home 'komp's daily drivel' after viewing that group post. I belive years ago and maybe many themes ago the group name on the group details block used to link back to the group the post belonged to. Now it doesn't seem to do so.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Reg